# How to unset/delete cookies using HTTPARTY

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm having a problem where cookies are being saved between multiple gets, is there not a way to clear them/delete them/unset them inbetween each get?

So far I've tried sending "Cookie" => "" with the header, self.class.cookies({}) before get, sending headers: {"Cookie" => ""} with the get, self.class.instance_variable_set("@default_cookies", HTTParty::CookieHash.new) and probably more variants that I've forgotten.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Would love to know what you found out